# .NET 6 Winforms separate forms control pop up freezing when unfocused and using native Windows file transfer pop up

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

In my Winforms app, I have a separate smaller window pop up form when a user clicks an item from the menu in my main form. Right now, this smaller form that pop ups has a button that once clicked, it will start copying files from one location to another.

There are a lot of files (over 6000) and I noticed that once I start the file copy procedure, when I click outside the window, like in my desktop or some other opened app, it shows that it is Not Responding on the top and everything is slightly greyed out. Interestingly, I can still see the files being copied in the destination folder when I have it opened even though the window says its Not Responding. This only happens when I minimize the pop up form or when I click outside of it.

Is there a way to fix this? I was wondering if also using the native Windows file transfer dialog/pop up might help, but I cant find good documentation on how to use it in a .NET 6 Winforms app.

[image: Pop up forms not responding when clicking outside once file transfers started, but files are still being copied]

Comment: _"Is there a way to fix this?"_ - Yes, learn about threading.

Comment: Or, don't learn about threading to the extent that you think you have to manage multithreading yourself, but do your file copying asyncronously so that the thread (whose job is to draw the UI) that you're tying up with the job of actually copying the files) can go back to its normal job of drawing the UI occasionally

Comment: [Stream.CopyToAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync) -- [File IO improvements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/file-io-improvements-in-dotnet-6/)

Comment: The most important thing to appreciate here is that Windows dedicates a thread to your app for processing all the user input messages. As the user clicks around, their actions are causing hundreds of messages to be queued up - mouse moves, clicks, key presses etc. That same thread is the thread that appears in your C# code button click handler and does "your code". While it is doing "your code" it is not off elsewhere doing what it normally would - eat the queue of messages. So you block it up into a loop of 100,000 file copies, and the messages pile up, Windows notices and fades the UI out

Comment: ..because it really is "not responding" as far as Windows is concerned. If you can execute your actions using asyncronous methods, then when the file copy is going on the thread that kickstarted the action (the one that normally eats the window message queue) will temporarily pause executing your lines of C# and disappear back off into the matrix, to get on with consuming the queue. When the file copy X finishes, it'll come back and take up from where it left off, start another file copy and then disappear back into the matrix again. No jammed UI. No complex threading logic

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model

Comment: *was wondering if also using the native windows file transfer* - it's not about the file transfer, it's about you keeping the thread that draws the UI busy with too much long running stuff. You can jam a UI into "not responding" with something as simple as `Thread.Sleep(30000)`. Always be mindful that the thread that runs your event handler code has to finish quickly, or at least be allowed to go back to drawing the UI periodically

Comment: @flackoverstow Would using a Backgroundworker not be necessary then? It seems like there are more efficient options

Comment: TAP is arguably simpler to implement than BGW, and is now the dominant form of allowing .net to make efficient limited resource use in a situation where resource blocking may occur. BGW predates TAP by many years, and is rare to see these days

Answer (score 0):

Since you perform your operations on the UI thread, you cause the UI thread to be locked until the copy operation is finished. This is why asynchronous programming is so important. When you call an asynchronous method, you can call it from UI with async await pattern and wait with ConfigureAwait(true) (to avoid losing context and cross thread error.) You can continue your operations in mdi parent form.

TL;DR
Make your method async Task till its Event Args like button click, data source change etc. (Make them async void) then wait them with await.

```
public async void SB_DownloadClick(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
   await DoDownloadAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
}

async Task DoDownloadAsync(CancellationToken ct = default){
  // TODO YOUR DOWNLOAD CONTEXT AND CODES

}
```

For more [information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Would using a Backgroundworker not be necessary then? It seems like there are more efficient options